# Get the value with one mysql-query

Tags: mysql

With the following query I get the values of the different classes

```
$query = xtc_db_query("-- " . __LINE__ . __FILE__ . "
  SELECT value
  FROM   " . TABLE_ORDERS_TOTAL . "
  WHERE  orders_id = " . $last_order . "
  AND    class = 'ot_shipping'
");
$orders_total_shipping = xtc_db_fetch_array($query);
$query = xtc_db_query("-- " . __LINE__ . __FILE__ . "
  SELECT value
  FROM   " . TABLE_ORDERS_TOTAL . "
  WHERE  orders_id = " . $last_order . "
  AND    class='ot_tax'
");
$orders_total_tax = xtc_db_fetch_array($query);
$query = xtc_db_query("-- " . __LINE__ . __FILE__ . "
  SELECT value
  FROM   " . TABLE_ORDERS_TOTAL . "
  WHERE  orders_id = " . $last_order . "
  AND    class='ot_total'
");
$orders_total = xtc_db_fetch_array($query);
```

Is it possible to get the values with one query?

Comment: Why dont you use a UNION, where you combine multiple queries to produce one result set.

Comment: Yes there is, check union or join

Comment: I'm not an expert with mysql.

Answer (score 0):

May be something like this

```
$query = xtc_db_query("-- " . __LINE__ . __FILE__ . "
  SELECT Case When class = 'ot_shipping' The value Else Null End As Shipping,
         Case When class = 'ot_tax' The value Else Null End As Tax,
         Case When class = 'ot_total' The value Else Null End As Total
  FROM   " . TABLE_ORDERS_TOTAL . "
  WHERE  orders_id = " . $last_order . "
");
$orders_total_shipping = xtc_db_fetch_array($query);
```

**Or:**

```
$query = xtc_db_query("-- " . __LINE__ . __FILE__ . "
  SELECT value
  FROM   " . TABLE_ORDERS_TOTAL . "
  WHERE  orders_id = " . $last_order . "
  AND    class = 'ot_shipping'
  Union All
  SELECT value
  FROM   " . TABLE_ORDERS_TOTAL . "
  WHERE  orders_id = " . $last_order . "
  AND    class='ot_tax'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT value
  FROM   " . TABLE_ORDERS_TOTAL . "
  WHERE  orders_id = " . $last_order . "
  AND    class='ot_total'
  ");
$orders_total = xtc_db_fetch_array($query);
```

Comment: With UNION there are still 3 queries, aren't?